# Como atribuir o valor de uma variável que esta em uma função JavaScript, para uma consulta SQL.

Tags: javascript, sql, asp

Eu tenho uma função javascript que obtém o valor do item selecionado em uma combobox, e gostaria de passar esse valor como parâmetro para uma consulta SQL para trazer os dados que estão relacionados ao valor obtido no selected do combobox em minha página asp, segue minha função javascript e minha consulta SQL.

```
function obterOpcaoSelecionada(){
//obter o elemento select
var formu = frmDados.cb_catinsumo.value;

//obter o índice da opção selecionada
var indiceSelecionada = elem.options.selectedIndex;
}
```

Código SQL:

```
    SELECT 
    id_insumo,nome_comercial 
FROM 
    tb_insumo
WHERE 
    id_catinsumo = 
            (   SELECT 
                    id_catinsumo as id
                FROM
                    tb_catinsumo
                WHERE
                    categoria_insumo ='parametroJavaScritp' 
            ) 
ORDER BY 
    nome_comercial
```

Comment: Everton, vai ter de usar AJAX. Sabe como usar? Quer javascript puro ou usa uma biblioteca como jQuery ou MooTools?

Comment: @Sergio nunca usei o AJAX,seria uma boa para aprender ,eu estou usando javascript puro, mas posso usar uma biblioteca jQuery se for o caso.

Comment: Você está usando asp puro ou asp.net?

Comment: estou usando asp puro @Marciano.Andrade.

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação está utilizando no asp? Você pode utilizar um objeto 'hiddenfield' e via javascript você preenche esse 'hiddenfield', fazendo a leitura do mesmo no codebehind. Exemplo: Preencho o 'hiddenfield' via javascript e no meu código C# faço a leitura desse 'hiddenfield' para fazer a pesquisa no banco de dados.

Comment: @Gustavuu era exatamente isso que eu estava pensando, ele não precisa criar um ´[WebMethod]´ para isso, seguindo da forma como tu disse eu acredito ser o mais ráppido

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade eu estou usando VbScript no asp.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `jQuery.ajax()` para realizar este procedimento.

**Exemplo**

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "pagina_que_fara_a_consulta.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { sua_variavel : conteudo },
    dataType: "html"
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Veja mais em https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Dá uma lida nas tags, ele não está usando php, mas sim asp.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade isso é um exemplo, ele também não está utilizando "pagina_que_fara_a_consulta", cabe a ele fazer as alterações de acordo com suas respectivas necessidades.